# Testing iPhone-only app on iPad without zooming?

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, screen-size

My case is:

- I am building an iPhone-only app.
- My test devices are iPhone 4s and iPad 4.
- I would like to support iPhone 5/5c/5s screen sizes, but I don't have the actual devices.
- Can I use the iPad to test the UI for iPhone 5/5c/5s screen size, but without the automatic zoom of the app - simply taking only the 640×1136?

Thanks.

Comment: No , just add images of double size named as @2x.png in your bundle ..it will run fine in iPhone 5

Comment: @h.kishan only if you UI scale correctly and/or the windows size is correct. There are actually many thins that can go wrong. Testing in the simulator will you best option if you do not have an 4" iOS device.

Comment: Thanks guys. Simulator it is, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the iPad has not setting to allow this, neither did Apple release any API to do this.